# Inserting an array to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

i have this two text fields that ask the user to put in two numbers that are limited to 49 numbers, so that i can have an array of number 1 to 50, or 151 to 200, or 27551 to 27600 any number but a series of 49 consecutive numbers, my problem is i dont know how to put them inside the database, i have no clue i have been searching for everything about inserting arrays but they dont work on my case,

**This is my form**

```
 <form id="form3" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>From:
    <input type="text" name="from" id="form_number" class="from" /> 
    - To:
    <input type="text" name="to" id="form_number" class="to" />
    </p>
    <p>Waybill Booklet:
    <select name="waybill_booklet[]" id="form_list">
        <?php
            do {  
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_Booklet['id_waybill_booklet']?>"><?php echo $row_Booklet['booklet_no']?></option>
        <?php
            } while ($row_Booklet = mysql_fetch_assoc($Booklet));
            $rows = mysql_num_rows($Booklet);
            if($rows > 0) {
            mysql_data_seek($Booklet, 0);
            $row_Booklet = mysql_fetch_assoc($Booklet);
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="status[]" value="4" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="form_button" value="OK!" />
    </p>
</form>
```

the 49 series of consecutive numbers will be inserted into the database with a foreign key what is chosen from the drop down menu, and a value of 4 that is in the hidden field, so basically there are 4 columns to my table 1 for primary key 1 for the series of numbers and 1 for the foreign key and the last will be the value of the numbers.

**This is my php code to get the series of numbers**

```
<?php
$booklet = $_POST['waybill_booklet'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$number = range($from,$to);

$count = 0;
$myArray = range($from,$to);
while($count<=49){
if($count<49){
    echo $myArray[$count]. ", ";
}else{
    echo $myArray[$count];
}
$count++;
}
?>
```

i dont know how to insert the data's

Comment: Are you looking for `implode()`?

Comment: If `from` and `two` are always 49 apart, why does the user need to enter both numbers? Just enter the first or last number, and calculate the other one.

Comment: i have all of that connection and stuff. i just need help on how to insert the data, i dont think implode will work, i just need that the series of numbers will be inserted into the database with different primary id's each

Comment: If that's what you need to do, just write a loop that inserts each number into a new row.

Comment: @Barmar it used to be any number but i limited it to 49 to lessen the user error of inputting i want it to be flexible so i can change it if the users wants to have 1-100 series

Comment: @Barmar im new to php and mysql can u help me with some sample codes, i only know basic mysql insert record queries basic stuff and this for me is above average level mysql :(

Comment: Why do you have brackets in the `waybill_booklet` and `status` names? This should only be used if you have a table of multiple inputs, and then you need brackets for all the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$waybill = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['waybill_booklet'][0]);
$status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status'][0]);
foreach (range($from, $to) as $number) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO yourTable (id, waybill, status) VALUES($number, '$waybill', '$status')");
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

You should also switch to PDO or mysqli, so you can use parametrized queries instead of substituting strings into the query. Then you don't need to escape the values like that.

Comment: by looking at this code, i think this will lead me to the correct path thanks barmar gonna test this out and accept the answer if it works out.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given i get this for $waybill and $status

Comment: See my comment above about not needing brackets after these input names.

Comment: thanks barmar, im almost there with this code you gave me. just some minor problems about variables being undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing this as an array (since you want to store this as bulk, I assume it will not involve any direct database level aggregation or computation), you can store it as a json string using the `json_encode($myArray_series_of_numbers)`. This gives you the flexibility to store them as a string column and when you retrieve it back, you can use `json_decode($model->series_of_numbers_column,true)` to get it back as an array for easy computation back in PHP.

Hope this helps

Comment: i wont store them in the database as an array, i just need them to be inside the datbase each with different primary id's each not as an array

Comment: Can you show an example of how it should look in the DB. that will probably help understand what you are exactly looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on using mysql in php  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp specifically the INSERT command. just build your data into variables instead of echo'ing it and then follow the guide to interact with a database

here is the auto increment tutorial to generate primary ids for each array element http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

you can greatly increase the speed of the inserts and do it in one submit by building a multiple insert sql string.. and then using the insert guide above to run it.

```
INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

Comment: yea i know the basic insert but how can i insert the variable $numbers to the database $numbers holds the series of numbers

Comment: @user3282248 after you clarified in abisheks answer you can do this using an auto increment table easily... just insert as you normally would associating them with the foreign key.. the primary auto increment key will keep them all separate

Comment: yea i have auto increment key for my primary id, but my problem here is how can i insert record for all of the numbers with just one submit,

Comment: Will each series be a new row or one single row for each series?

Comment: a new row for each number not the series, but all the number inside the series will have a new row, so when user inputs 1-50, their will be 49 new rows with different primary key

Comment: Yes, @clancer, answer should help you with multiple inserts with a single insert call, prevent using a `for-loop` to `insert` if you are sure about the `bulk inserts`, if you want to perform any operation for each insert, then you will have to use @Barmar's answer